# mapping back any sklearn result to the original dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, sklearn-pandas

I'd like to analyze the predicted values of my random forest results in excel with the original test data as a reference.

The predicted result comes in an array as i use this:

```
predict = rf.predict(test[columns])
```

how do I map back the predicted results to the original dataset using pandas?

Regards,
galeej

Comment: I think you need to explain your scenario a little more clearly. Maybe put in some example data as well.

Comment: You should be able to just add this back as a new column: `test['prediction'] = rf.predict(test[columns])`

Comment: My apologies for the delayed reply...@EdChum your method worked... thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EdChum's answered the question.

(Edit) His answer:

> You should be able to just add this back as a new column:
>   test['prediction'] = rf.predict(test[columns])

My apologies for the delay.

Regards,
Sunil